# What does `array[^1]` mean in C# compiler?

Tags: c#, indexing, unary-operator

```cs
int[] numbers = new int[10];
numbers[9] = 10;
Console.Write(numbers[^1] == numbers[numbers.Count()-1]); //true
```

How does index of `^1` returns the last item in an array?

What does `^1` mean in C# compiler?

Does it have performance benefit vs `numbers[numbers.Count()-1]`?

Comment: Perhaps you should read the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#runtime-behavior. Also, it's obviously better than using `numbers.Count()-1` since `Count()` is a Linq method that needs to iterate through the entire array.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: `Enumerable.Count()` is a little smarter than that -- if applied to anything that implements `ICollection` (which includes arrays) it will just get the `.Count` of that. There's still overhead, but far less than if the whole array had to be iterated.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm very aware of that, but that's an implementation detail that can change in the future :)

Comment: Okay this is C#  8 feature, but what is equivalent code for this in C# 7? What is `^1` translated to?

Comment: that's all well described in Camilo Terevinto's link...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`numbers[^1]` is the same with `numbers[length-1]`

They are called ranged operators in C#  8. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) for more details.